# Why position absolute affects opacity?

Tags: html, css

I have come across an interesting moment for myself and would like to figure out how it works.

Here are 2 examples in the sandbox. On one without position: absolute, the opacity is different from where position: absolute is applied. Why does positioning affect the degree of opacity in this case?

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.text-wrap {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #202122FF;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.text {
  right: 40%;
  bottom: -7px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #202122FF;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-wrap">
    <span class="text">
              Some text
            </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: preview with position: absolute]

And the same template without position: absolute

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.text-wrap {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #202122FF;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.text {
  right: 40%;
  bottom: -7px;
  /* position: absolute; */
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #202122FF;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-wrap">
    <span class="text">
              Some text
            </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: preview without position: absolute]

Comment: Both examples render with the same shades of grey on my machine.

Comment: Do you by chance have multiple of these on the page? I'm guessing when you apply `position: absolute;`, they are overlapping eachother and stacking, appearing darker.

Comment: use another background-color to see what is happening, or set `.text-wrap{line-height:0;}` ... opacity and position are not involved, just where stands your span.

Comment: Update: this issue reproducing only on Chrome macos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about position, but where stands the span .

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.text-wrap {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #202122FF;
  opacity: 0.5;
  line-height:0/* span/text  will overflow now */
}

.text {
  right: 40%;/* no effect on static position*/
  bottom: -7px;/* no effect on static position*/
  /* position: absolute; */
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #202122FF;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text-wrap">
    <span class="text">
              Some text
            </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah. This is a working solution. Thank you. But it's also interesting why the opacity changes when position: absolute is applied.

Answer (score 1):

You have opacity set on the wrapper of that element. If the wrapper has opacity then it will transfer to the children of the element. To fix you need to move the text somewhere on the outside of the element.

```css
  .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
  }

  .text-wrap {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #202122FF;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  .text {
    right: 40%;
    bottom: -7px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: #202122FF;
    background-color: white;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="text-wrap">
        
      </div>
      <span class="text">
        Some text
      </span>
    </div>
```